# Bootstrap desktop & mobile layouts push pull on w3schools

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to achieve the following. **Mockup:** http://pasteboard.co/iNg55T4.png

The code below looks good on mobile (xs) but on desktop (md or greater) the positioning is wrong. I have tried all sorts of push/pull but to no avail. Im using w3schools website to play around with their editor and have the code below.

And using this link and code at w3 schools
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_stacked_to_hor&stacked=h

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      <p>1 this is div 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
      <p>2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div 2 2 this is div</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      <p>3 this is div 3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      <p>4 this is div 4</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

If anyone could help answer this puzzle it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is as far I can push It http://jsfiddle.net/q4Lhv3f3/, see if you can pull it more :)

Comment: Good try!! Yes this was my best effort too. On Desktop (full width) I just couldn't get div 3 up higher to fill in that white space.